# Travelling to Poland and then UK - Which visa for the latter?

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel

I am travelling from India to Poland for viewing a music concert (Schengen in progress) for 4 days, and then heading to UK for viewing another concert. Which visa should I apply for for the UK visit? Will the Standard Visitor Visa work? I will be applying from India, but going from Poland to UK.

Please read: I will be travelling to Germany in the month of August, the Schengen visa is for that. This trip in question, was planned later. Stay - Poland 3 days, UK - 8 days. This is my first international travel, however I have my family, a stable well paying job, my investments and assets, and most importantly my band here. I believe those are good enough ties to my country. :D

Comment: AFAIK, visas don't care where you're travelling from, they care about your passport.

Comment: Will you be _audience_ to those concerts, or are you _performing_ in them? If performing, will you be paid for the gig?

Comment: @Martha Great! I have a legit passport then! Thanks.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I will be an audience. Wait, I will add that detail to the question.

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde The typical approach when travelling to several jurisdictions is to apply for the necessary visas in reverse order, in other words you should obtain the visa relating to your final destination first. In your case, having the UK visa in place before applying for your Schengen visa should strengthen your case for the latter. Without it your visit premise is only a 4 day trip, which from India may not seem credible to the ECO.

Comment: @Traveller: I assume that "(Schengen in progress)" means that the OP has already lodged his application for a Schengen visa. So the outcome of that will be what it will be.

Comment: @Traveller Understood. Here's another fact about my travel with respect to what you have mentioned: I will be travelling to Germany in the month of August for 8 days, and the Schengen application is for the same purpose. It hasn't started yet, it will by the next week. An event management company is doing that so it is not in my control.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Read my comment above! :)

Comment: @Henning Makholm Agreed - and of course the OP doesn’t state the intended length of the UK visit, or whether they have a previous travel history. It’s possibly a chicken and egg scenario in that the trip may only stack up as a whole but if each leg is brief attending a concert may not be seen as a strong premise for a long journey from India by either jurisdiction.

Comment: @Traveller About 3 days in Poland and 8 days in UK. I don't have an international travel history! :)

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde Henning Makholm’s answer remains valid but it would be helpful if you edited the additional information in your comment into your original question. If you don’t have a prior travel history, hopefully you do have strong ties to your home.

Comment: @Traveller Agreed, done. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Standard Visitor visa is definitely the right visa for being in the audience for a concert -- no matter where you're going before or after. Such a visit is an ordinary touristic purpose, so you should apply for a visa in the same way as other tourists.